# Convert deprecated methods from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I am translating a code from Java to Kotlin with Android Studio, but I have the problem.

When I use this:

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener)
```

Android Studio tells me `setOnActionExpandListener` is deprecated in Java. So how can I convert this code in Kotlin ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem,%20android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener)) and do what's suggested to you.

> **This method was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-beta1.**
>   Use `setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener)` directly.

The `setOnActionExpandListener()` was added with Android version 14 and since the Support libraries in version 26 requires the same version, there's no need for using it with the compatibility method.